# Symfony2: Route without slash in the end?

Tags: php, symfony

I have this controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/products")
 */
class ProductAdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="product_list")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="product_new")
     */
    public function newAction()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="product_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }
}
```

When I go to the page `/admin/products` Symfony redirects me to the `/admin/products/`. But I want my routes be consistent without slash in the end.

If I omit slash in listAction:

```
/**
 * @Route(name="product_list")
 */
public function listAction()
{
}
```

Now route works OK without redirect. But I don't know it's correct or not. Because all examples use "/" for root route.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `@route` annotation above the class declaration,
and then state the full route for your actions.

Beside the `indexAction`, other routes shouldn't display a `/` at the end of they URL as they're, but you will have to precede them with `/admin/products` as well.

```
class ProductAdminController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/products", name="product_list")
     */
    public function listAction() {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/products/new", name="product_new")
     */
    public function newAction() {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin/products/{id}/delete", name="product_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction() {
    }
}
```